# Заголовки X-Lognex-* и X-RateLimit не приходят в ответе

Tags: postman, moysklad-json-api

Согласно документации заголовки X-RateLimit и X-Lognex-* должны сопровождать ответы на запросы:
[https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#header-обработка-ошибок](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#header-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA)

---

**Вот пример запросов GET:**

не приходят

https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/productfolder/?offset=100&limit=100

приходят (при любом пустом rows: [] )

https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/productfolder/?offset=500&limit=100

Так же выяснилось, что при запросах **HEAD** обе ссылки возвращают эти заголовки.

---

*Программа для обработки запросов:* Postman

*Аутентификация:* BasicAuth

Comment: Очень похоже на баг, обратитсь в поддержку и подробно опишите ситуацию

Comment: Изначально так и сделал, а послали сюда задать вопрос..